# How to make a proxy model's relationships return proxy models themselves

Tags: python, django

I've got a simple model relationship:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    ...

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    ...
```

but I've *also* got some proxy models building on top of those models:

```
class ProxyAuthor(Author):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class ProxyBook(Book):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Is there a way to get `ProxyAuthor.objects.get(pk=123).books()` to return `ProxyBook` objects rather than `Book` objects?

Comment: Likely not, since the fields in the proxy model are not a "clone" of the ones in the base model, but exactly the same instances.